# Grabbing parameter data from Codeigniter URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a CI project and have a need to send data to a controller as a url parameter. I am used to doing something like this.

```
<a href="site/controller/function?id=1">
```

Then I am able to grab the parameter using $_GET.

However I was told to use this method.

```
<a href="site/controller/function/1">
```

I did this and it shows up in the url when I click on the link, but I have no idea how to grab the actual parameter.

Any advice?

Comment: This is a route parameter.  You can devise a makeshift way of getting these but I'd suggest using a framework that provides routing to you.  Using GET variables will suffice however.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I used the following.

```
$id=$this->uri->segment(3);
```

And this got me the id number I passed.

Answer (score 0):

You better should use like below in your codeIgniter function. Even though your code also fine.

```
function funcName ($param1)
{
 echo $param1;
}
```